# laravel 4.2 - database without using migrations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I made a database by running sql queries.

mysql query for staff table is as follows.

```
use highwaymate;

create table staff(
  staff_ID int auto_increment primary key,
  first_name varchar(50) not null,
  last_name varchar(50) not null,
  title enum('miss','mrs','mr','ms') not null,
  address varchar(500) not null,
  date_of_birth date,
  email varchar(50),
  telephone varchar(10),
  role enum('academic','non academic'),
  designation_ID int,
  contract_type enum('temporary','permanent'), 
  etf_number varchar(15),
  NIC varchar(10) not null,
  date_started date not null,
  resigned_date date,
  timestamp datetime default now(),
  constraint fk_staff foreign key(designation_ID) references designations(designation_ID) on update cascade
);
```

my Staff model is as follows

```
<?php

class Staff extends Eloquent
{
  protected $table = 'staff';
  protected $primaryKey='staff_ID';
  protected $timepstamps=false;
  public $incrementing=false;

}
```

my route is as follows

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'csrf'),function(){
  Route::post('/category/index/staff/new',array('uses'=>'CategoryController@postStaffAdd', 'as' => 'category-postStaffAdd'));
});
```

my Staff Controller is as follows

```
<?php

class CategoryController extends BaseController {

    public function index(){

      return View::make('categories.index');
    }

    public function staffIndex()
    {
      $staff = Staff::all();
      return View::make('categories.staffpage')->with('staff',$staff);
    }

    public function staffAdd(){
      return View::make('categories.staffadd');
    }

    public function postStaffAdd(){

      $staff = new Staff;

      $staff->first_name = 'John';

      $staff->last_name = 'Dalton';

      $staff->title = 'mr';

      $staff->address = 'Panagoda, Hoamgama';

      $staff->date_of_birth = '1990-12-21';

      $staff->email = 'johnnydalton@gmail.com';

      $staff->telephone = '0775698521';

      $staff->role = 'academic';

      $staff->designation_ID = 3;

      $staff->contract_type = 'permanent';

      $staff->etf_number = 'pending';

      $staff->NIC = '901254586V';

      $staff->date_started = '2015-05-02';

      $staff->save();

      return "You have entered a new staff member successfully";
    }



}
```

**My problem is `postStaffAdd()` method, it is not working.**

Following is the error I found=>

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `staff` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `title`, `address`, `date_of_birth`, `email`, `telephone`, `role`, `designation_ID`, `contract_type`, `etf_number`, `NIC`, `date_started`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (John, Dalton, mr, Panagoda, Hoamgama, 1990-12-21, johnnydalton@gmail.com, 0775698521, academic, 3, permanent, pending, 901254586V, 2015-05-02, 2016-02-05 09:59:57, 2016-02-05 09:59:57))

Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
```

I feel; there is a problem in data types because string fields such as `first_name` seems non string when I see the arguments. Is that a problem?

Help me to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *note that I didn't use migrations in my project.

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting an error? If you don't provide enough information we can't help you.

Comment: my problem is postStaffAdd() method, it is not working. it gives an error, it says something went wrong

Comment: Check the error log in `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` and edit your question to include the error you're getting.

Comment: Set in config/app.php debug to true so you can check the error too.

Comment: What you mean when you say you didn't use migration? Does table exists in DB?

Try this and let us know what error is prints on screen?

try{
      $staff->save();
      }catch(Exception $e){
        dd($e->message());
      }

Comment: thanks a lot, i improved my question now

Comment: Nimmi, change  protected $timepstamp='false'; to public $timestamps = false; in your Staff model.

Comment: updated_at, created_at still comes. please help me to clear this

Comment: my problem solved, thank all you guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misspelled the property name that is used to disable timestamps in your `Staff` model and the property must be `public` not `protected` So instead of:

```
protected $timepstamps = false;
//             ^
// There's an extra "p" in the property name
```

It should be:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

As shown in the [Laravel Eloquent Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#timestamps).

Comment: Then please explain what's the new problem. What error are you getting after you fixed the timestamps issue?

Comment: Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException

Comment: Please post the entire error. That's only the exception class that was triggered for the error.

Comment: Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22)
HELP
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `staff` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `title`, `address`, `date_of_birth`, `email`, `telephone`, `role`, `designation_ID`, `contract_type`, `etf_number`, `NIC`, `date_started`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (nimmi, rashinika, ms, 610/68 homagama, 1993-09-20, nimmirashinika@gmail.com, 0713334413, non acedemic, 3, temporary, pending, 9312534502v, 2016-01-01, 2016-02-05 10:12:49, 2016-02-05 10:12:49))

Comment: You still have the property name misspelled. I've update my answer to point that out, as well as to provide additional information.

Comment: thanks a lot :-) all my problems were solved after you pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't using migrations, your table doesn't have the default `timestamps`added by laravel (ie. created_at and updated_at columns).

You have two ways to sort this out:

- Either adding the columns to the table (preferably via a [migration](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations))
- Or telling your model you won't use the timestamps, like so

`protected $timestamps = false;`

Comment: thnks shempignon :-)